Ruby - all permutations with any number of elements
I want to transform the array [3, 4, 8] → [3, 4, 8, 34, 38, 48, 43, 83, 84, 348, 384, 834, 843, 438, 483]
I tried array.permutation but this only returns [348, 384, 834, 843, 438, 483]. Is there a clean way of doing this without generating every possible subset first?

I assume from your selection of the answer below that the order of the elements in the desired array is not important. If you had said that some of us would not have wasted time by taking your question at face value.

Array#permutation takes one optional parameter telling it what maximum permutation size to create.
In your case, you just want all permutations of size 1, then 2, then 3, ... up to your input.count.
So it's as simple as creating a range of those numbers, mapping over them calling permutation with a different number each time, and combining the results:
def all_permutations_of(input)
  (1..input.count).flat_map do |permutation_length|
    input.permutation(permutation_length).to_a
  end
end

p all_permutations_of([3, 4, 8])
# => [
#   [3], [4], [8],
#   [3, 4], [3, 8], [4, 3], [4, 8], [8, 3], [8, 4],
#   [3, 4, 8], [3, 8, 4], [4, 3, 8], [4, 8, 3], [8, 3, 4], [8, 4, 3],
# ]

And if you want those digits as actual numbers like you show in your example, you'll need a little function to combine them together, like this one I affectionately call "smoosh":
# Produces a single number from an array of digits
# E.g. `[1, 2, 3]` becomes `123`
def smoosh(digits)
  exponent = digits.count
  
  digits.sum do |digit|
    exponent -= 1
    digit * (10 ** exponent)
  end
end

p all_permutations_of([3, 4, 8]).map { smoosh(_1) }
# => [3, 4, 8, 34, 38, 43, 48, 83, 84, 348, 384, 438, 483, 834, 843]


You could chain permutations of each size together and then turn it into an array:
ary = [3, 4, 8]
Enumerator::Chain.new(
  *ary.map.with_index(1) { ary.permutation(_2) }
).map(&:join).map(&:to_i)

#=> [3, 4, 8, 34, 38, 43, 48, 83, 84, 348, 384, 438, 483, 834, 843]


map(&:join).map(&:to_i) could of course be combined: map { |a| a.join.to_i }. I personally have no preference.

Alternatively you could utilize Enumerator#+ to chain them and write (1..ary.size).map { |i| ary.permutation(i) }.inject(:+).map { |a| a.join.to_i }

inject(:+) on arrays produces a lot of intermediate arrays. Your solution would run faster and be more clear if you used flatten or flat_map, which is a perfect fit for this case

@Alexander those are enumerators, not arrays. The result is an enumerator chain.

@Stefan Ah yes, you're right
